# preg_split string into letter pairs

Tags: php, regex, arrays, string, preg-split

I'm having way too much trouble with this simple problem: split a string into an array of 2-character values, i.e.

```
$string = 'abcdefgh';

// With the correct regex, should return ['ab','cd','ef','gh'];
$array = preg_split("/?????/",$string);
```

What's the darn regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) instead.

```
$chunks = str_split($string, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If you split ON the characters, you end up with an array of 4 elements that are blank

eg.

`/../i`

I don't think the preg_split is what you want, perhaps `preg_match_all`? eg.

`$cnt = preg_match_all('/../i', $string, $matches);`

Comment: Your welcome, with str_split (below) I also commented that you have to be careful of UTF-8 chars as str_split is by byte-length

Comment: The `i` flag is entirely useless.