# Split string into into array of character pairs

Tags: php, arrays, string, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP preg_split string into letter pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118789/php-preg-split-string-into-letter-pairs)

I have an string looking like this:

```
$str = "How are you doing?";
```

How can I turn this string into an array looking like this:

```
$arr = array("Ho","w ","ar","r ","yo","u ","do","in","g?");
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$array = str_split($str, 2);
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/str_split).

Answer (score 4):

Use [`str_split()` function](http://pl2.php.net/manual/pl/function.str-split.php).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [str_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php); it allows you to split a string by a definable amount of characters, so your code would look like:

```
$arr = str_split($str, 2);
```

Which will split `$str` into an array `$arr` where each element contains two characters,